# Find the Proportion of Two Events Occurring

Tags: probability

Hi I understand this may be a bit of a simple question, but I'm not able to get a correct answer at all for the following question:

"In a recent survey it was found that $50\%$ of investors placed their money in Apple shares while $60\%$ invested in Google.
Of the people surveyed, $15\%$ invested in neither of these.

Find the proportion of investors that had both Apple and Google shares."

I have tried calculating as two independent events: $$Pr(A∩B)=Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)=0.5\cdot 0.6=0.3,$$ which is incorrect.

According to the answers, the correct answer should be $0.25$, but I'm not able to find this at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are encouraged to edit your post to include your attempt even if it fails.

Comment: As a suggestion:  Assign variables to each of the unknown types of investors.  Thus, let $a$ be the portion of "Amazon only" investors, $b$ the "both", $c$ the "Google only".  That's three unknowns so find three equations and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(A) = 0.5, P(G)=0.6$$

$$1-P(A \cup G)=0.15$$

$$P(A\cup G) = 0.85$$

$$P(A)+P(G)-P(A \cap G)=0.85$$

$$0.5+0.6-P(A \cap G)=0.85$$

$$P(A \cap G)=1.1-0.85=0.25$$

The reason your method doesn't work is because the event of buying apple stocks and google stocks are not independent.

Comment: Thank you!! I hadn't even thought of that, you are a lifesaver